# Goodwillie derivatives of $X \mapsto \Sigma^\infty X\text{^}^n/\Sigma_n$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I'm following Arone's lectures on Goodwillie calculus from Munster 2015. There he left an exercise:

> Find $\partial_kF$ for $F: \text{Top}_* \to \text{Sp}$ given by $F(X) = \Sigma^\infty X\text{^}^n/\Sigma_n$  where $X\text{^}^n = X \wedge \cdots \wedge X$ and $\Sigma_n$ is the symmetric group, which acts on $X\text{^}^n$ by permuting factors.

In the lectures he solves the case $n = 2$, that gives $\partial_1 F \simeq \Sigma^\infty\Sigma\mathbb{RP}^\infty$, $\partial_2F \simeq \Sigma^\infty$ and $\partial_nF \simeq *$.

I do not know how to work out the general case. I know that $\partial_kF \simeq \text{hocolim }\Omega^{km}\text{cr}_kF(S^m, \dots, S^m)$.

For $k = 1$ then $\partial_1F \simeq \text{hocolim }\Omega^mF(S^m)$. Now, if I am right

$(S^m)\text{^}^n/\Sigma_n \cong \text{subset}_{\leq n}(\mathbb{R^m})^+ \cong S^m \wedge \text{subset}_{\leq n, 0}(\mathbb{R^m})^+$

where $(\cdots)^+$ means compactification, $\text{subset}_{\leq n}(\cdots)$ is the space of subsets of cardinality $\leq n$ and $\text{subset}_{\leq n, 0}(\mathbb{R^m})$ is the space of those with barycenter 0. Then $\partial_1F \simeq \Sigma^\infty\text{subset}_{\leq n, 0}(\mathbb{R^\infty})$. This agrees with the previous result for $n = 2$ since any two unordered points can be identified by the line joining them ($\mathbb{RP}^\infty$) and the distance from 0 ($\Sigma$, after compactification). But

1. It does not seem to be the "right solution".
2. What about $\partial_nF$ for $n > 1$? I do not know how to proceed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: oh nice. Off the cuff maybe restricting to the cyclic action should give $\Sigma^\infty \Sigma L_n^\infty$ (infinite loop space) for the first derivative. I don't know the answer, +1. There are definitely some people here that can answer this, but if nobody answers in a few days, try MO (where Arone is a member, I believe.)

Comment: @AndresMejia In general we have $(S^m)^{\wedge n}/\Sigma_n \cong S^m \wedge (S^m)^{\wedge (n-1)}/\Sigma_n$ where the new action depends on the map $\phi: (S^m)^{\wedge n} \to (S^m)^{\wedge (n-1)}$  chosen to obtain the homeomorphism $(x_1, \dots, x_n) \mapsto (x_1 + \cdots + x_m, \phi(x_1, \dots, x_n))$. Sincerly, I do not know how to choose $\phi$ in order to get a nice action!

Comment: @AndresMejia If you are interested, you find the exercises here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5zU6pWVUeRVeTRKSThnWTcyVDk1SmVqeVlkSzNoQjc1bW5N/view?usp=sharing